# Register an OS X Service to accept no input or NSPasteboard input

Tags: macos, info.plist

I'm trying my hand at creating an OS X service that outputs [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) style links from a URL in the clipboard. I want it to be able to handle selected text input **and** cases where there's no text selection.

I've been following Apple's [Services Implementation Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/SysServices/introduction.html), and by setting `NSSendTypes` to `NSStringPBoardType` the service can properly accept selected text, and if I remove the `NSSendTypes` key it will run without selected text, but I can't find a way to have my service accessible in both situations.

Is there an Info.plist key I can set to allow this behaviour, or am I restricted to one or the other?

Comment: Can you share a sample xcode project that can be used to try out some approaches?

Comment: Sure, here you go: http://db.tt/A2PvalfG

Comment: This is probably unrelated but the documentation says, `NSPasteboardTypeString` should be used in place of `NSStringPBoardType` as it is deprecated from 10.6 and onwards.

Comment: What happens when there's no selection?

Comment: If it's set such that it takes a selection, the service will be disabled whenever there's no selection. I haven't looked into the `NSPasteboardTypeString` vs. `NSStringPBoardType` yet, but I imagine it won't change the other behaviour (good to know though, thanks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted Apple's Developer Support about this issue, and after a bit of investigating, they told me that this is currently not possible (as of September 25, 2012).

I have filed an enhancement request on bugreport.apple.com, which you can [view on Open Radar](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=2038403) if you're interested (by all means, file duplicates with Apple if you'd like the same thing added).